# How to preserve overall indentation level of selection with Sublime HTML/CSS/JS Prettify

Tags: html, sublimetext3, indentation, prettify

I have indentation set to char=tab, and levels=1 for Prettify for Sublime. Works great on a whole document. However, if I use it on a selection, which naturally already has a certain level of indentation, it left justifies the entire block while proceeding to correctly tab indent the code.

My question is how do I get Prettify the overall code while leaving it in it's place?

I'm cutting over from 15 or so years of Dreamweaver, and something simple like this is real pain to not have.

Thanks

Comment: Are you prettifying one language mainly (and if so, which one?) or do you use all three pretty much evenly? The reason I ask is there are a number of other plugins that may work for you.

Comment: In this case, only HTML is the problem. I'm using HTML/CSS/JS Prettify. I don't need this kind of feature with other languages, because only HTML gets all nested and crazy, especially when working with Bootstrap

Comment: OK, let me see what I can find for you